# Scripts/styles not loading on cloned WP Site when logged in

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, 404-error, hosting, staging

I've cloned a WordPress site using installatron (on cPanel). The front-end loads fine when not logged in, but when I am logged in, scripts & styles aren't loading and changes I make to plugin options are saving, but not applying (e.g. I added 'restricted site access' as the site is intended for dev/staging purposes. The options to redirect is saving but the site is still accessible by the public. I can't add IP addressed to the ignore list though).

The console shows 404 errors for the js/css files.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: Copy the URL for the CSS or JS files and paste in your browser address bar. If it opens the file, then the URL is fine. If it doesn't, you need to check the folder to see if the files exist there or not.

Comment: I am getting 404 errors when I put the url into my browser, but I've FTP'd into the server and can see all the files there, so I can't understand why...

Comment: If your browser is not able to access it, then it's most likely an incorrect address. But how about checking access logs to see if it is related to permissions?

Comment: Often when something is different logged in vs. not logged in, it's due to caching. Can you check whether any caching plugins or server caching are enabled? Have you checked with an Incognito window or cleared cache? Are you using a CDN that might be expecting things to be at a different URL?